# Issue when compiling Cython code with OpenMP flag on Windows

Tags: gcc, openmp, cython

I am trying to compile Cython code with the GCC compiler (which usually works like a charm), and as recommended on the "Using Parallelism" page I add the "-fopenmp" command to my setup file. However, when compiling I get the following error:
gcc.exe: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory

My version of gcc is 4.5.2, which I believe should support OpenMP just fine. I'm working on 64-bit Windows 7.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you find libgomp.spec on your system? On my install (pythonxy) it is located at `C:\MinGW32-xy\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2\libgomp.spec`.

Comment: Thanks! The file is indeed missing in the install directory. I should add that if I check my command line gcc command for its install location, it seems to be pointing to a location inside my Python directory, rather than a separate MinGW folder. I do have a separate MinGW install, with gcc 4.6.1 with libgomp.spec present, on my drive, but it does not seem to be using this by default.
I'm a little surprised it's using this MinGW hidden inside my Python folder, and I think I'll try pointing to the alternative gcc command, unless you can think of a reason this could create other problems?